# C# OData Unchase select sinle

Tags: c#, select, odata

I've set up OData context and I want to recieve a single entity. So I tried something like this:

```
var ltbk = ctx.LTBkSet.Single(p => p.Lgnum == "004" && p.Tbnum == "0000125481");
```

Unfortunatelly I´m recieving this error

```
        "System.NotSupportedException : 
    This target framework does not enable you to directly enumerate over a data service query. 
This is because enumeration automatically sends a synchronous request to the data service. 
Because this framework only supports asynchronous operations, 
you must instead call the BeginExecute and EndExecute methods 
to obtain a query result that supports enumeration."
```

How can I make an ansynchronous operation with a single entity?
There are varios examples with an entityset, but I need a single entity.

Comment: Post the *full* exception text and the code that actually throws. This error wasn't thrown by EF's `Single()`. You can get the full text with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup

Comment: There's method `SingleAsync`, which is asynchronous :)

Comment: Which runtime (.NET Old or .NET Core) is involved? Which OData packages, which versions? Googling for the error message returns at least one possibly duplicate question, where .NET Old code was used with an old .NET Core OData library. The latest OData libraries for .NET Core have fixed a *lot* of problems

Comment: The duplicate demonstrates how important the missing information is - I answered the duplicate in the comments, and yet I couldn't understand what the current question was, just from the exception text and incomplete code. I'm pretty sure recent OData libraries wouldn't even talk about `BeginExecute`, they'd tell you to use `ExecuteAsync`

Comment: I have:   "ProviderId": "Unchase.OData.ConnectedService",
  "Version": "1.3.3.0",                               there is no ExecuteAsync or SingleAsync

Comment: There is only BeginExecute and EndExecute.

Comment: I got it.I have to do it this way: `var ltbk2 = ctx.LTBkSet; IAsyncResult cekacka2 = ltbk2.BeginExecute(ReadingLTBK2, ltbk2);                 var people = peopleQuery.EndExecute(ar)
                      .Single(p => p.Lgnum == "004" && p.Tbnum == "0000125482");`